# `mstate`: prepare "long" format data into "mstate" format data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

The typical preparation steps for `mstate` involve converting "wide" format data (1x row per 'patient') into "multi-state" format data (multiple rows per 'patient' for each possible transition in the multi-state model).

For example, data in wide format:

```
library(mstate)

data(ebmt4)
ebmt <- ebmt4

> head(ebmt)
  id  rec rec.s   ae ae.s recae recae.s  rel rel.s  srv srv.s      year agecl proph              match
1  1   22     1  995    0   995       0  995     0  995     0 1995-1998 20-40    no no gender mismatch
2  2   29     1   12    1    29       1  422     1  579     1 1995-1998 20-40    no no gender mismatch
3  3 1264     0   27    1  1264       0 1264     0 1264     0 1995-1998 20-40    no no gender mismatch
4  4   50     1   42    1    50       1   84     1  117     1 1995-1998 20-40    no    gender mismatch
5  5   22     1 1133    0  1133       0  114     1 1133     0 1995-1998   >40    no    gender mismatch
6  6   33     1   27    1    33       1 1427     0 1427     0 1995-1998 20-40    no no gender mismatch
```

Is converted to multi-state format:

```
tmat <- transMat(x = list(c(2, 3, 5, 6), c(4, 5, 6), c(4, 5, 6), c(5, 6), c(), c()), names = c("Tx", "Rec", "AE", "Rec+AE", "Rel", "Death"))
msebmt <- msprep(data = ebmt, trans = tmat, time = c(NA, "rec", "ae", "recae", "rel", "srv"), status = c(NA, "rec.s", "ae.s", "recae.s", "rel.s", "srv.s"), keep = c("match", "proph", "year", "agecl"))

> head(msebmt)
An object of class 'msdata'

Data:
  id from to trans Tstart Tstop time status              match proph      year agecl
1  1    1  2     1      0    22   22      1 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
2  1    1  3     2      0    22   22      0 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
3  1    1  5     3      0    22   22      0 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
4  1    1  6     4      0    22   22      0 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
5  1    2  4     5     22   995  973      0 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
6  1    2  5     6     22   995  973      0 no gender mismatch    no 1995-1998 20-40
```

But what if my original dataset has time-varying covariates (i.e. long format) and I want to format the data into multi-state mode?  All of the tutorials I have found online are only for converting initially wide data to multi-state data (not initially long data); for example the mstate package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mstate/vignettes/Tutorial.pdf).

So, let's say I have the below data `df`, where id is for a 'patient', (`start`,`stop`] tell us the time periods, `state` is the state the patient is in at the end of the time period, and `tv.cov` is their time-varying covariate (assumed constant over the time period).  Note that only patient `id=5` has 3x entries and that person's `tv.cov` changes.

```
  id start stop state tv.cov
   1     0    1     1      1
   2     0    4     1      2
   3     0    7     1      1
   4     0   10     1      5
   5     0    6     1      4
   5     6   10     2     10
   5    10   15     3     12
```

Assuming the basic "illness-death" transition model:

```
tmat <- mstate::trans.illdeath(names = c("healthy", "sick", "death"))

> tmat
         to
from      healthy sick death
  healthy      NA    1     2
  sick         NA   NA     3
  death        NA   NA    NA
```

How can I prep `df` into multi-state format?

As a hack, should I setup the data in "wide" format, format the data into "multi-state" format using `msprep` and then join another frame onto it which contains the time-varying covariates for each patient at each time interval?

Comment: I doubt that I will have time to do this task but the first function I would be looking at would be `tmerge`.

Comment: I’ll take another look at `tmerge` but didn’t think it would be helpful here (as my data is already in ‘long’ format).  But what are you thinking regarding `tmerge`?  High-levels steps / clues are helpful

Comment: I was thinking you had two long format data objects and you needed to create multiple lines of data for each individual.